# Write a string to file not equal to string that read from it

Tags: c++, file, binary, binaryfiles

#### Phase 1

example 1: I have `string text = "01100001"` then I want write to file `"a"`
example 2: I have `string text = "0110000101100010"` So I want write to file `"ab"`

`NOTE:`I solved `phase 1` and result of writing is true.

#### Phase 2

for example 1:

> > I want read the file and put it to temp.
> >     So temp = "a" and i convert it to "01100001"

for example 2:

> > I want read the file and put it to temp.
> >     So temp = "ab" and i convert it to "0110000101100010"

#### Question

in my code i have below input

```
    string text ="00000110101011100010001011111110011011110101100101110101101111010111111110101011"
"00111011000011100011100000100010111110111110111001100001110001110000101001111010"
"00000101";
```

I did "phase 1" and I opened the file in a hex editor the writing is true.
But after doing "phase 2" temp != text. Why?

#### My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class bitChar{
public:
    unsigned char* c;
    int shift_count;
    string BITS;

    bitChar()
    {
        shift_count = 0;
        c = (unsigned char*)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    }

    string readByBits(ifstream& inf)
    {
        string s ="";
        while (inf)
        {
            string strInput;
            getline(inf, strInput );

            for (int i =0 ; i < strInput.size() ; i++)
            {
                s += getBits(strInput[i]);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    void setBITS(string X)
    {
        BITS = X;
    }

    int insertBits(ofstream& outf)
    {
        int total = 0 ;
        while(BITS.length())
        {
            if(BITS[0] == '1')
                *c |= 1;
            *c <<= 1;
            ++shift_count;
            ++total;
            BITS.erase(0, 1);

            if(shift_count == 7 )
            {
                if(BITS.size()>0)
                {
                    if(BITS[0] == '1')
                        *c |= 1;
                    ++total;
                    BITS.erase(0, 1);
                }

                writeBits(outf);
                shift_count = 0;
                free(c);
                c = (unsigned char*)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
            }
        }

        if(shift_count > 0)
        {
            *c <<= (7 - shift_count);
            writeBits(outf);
            free(c);
            c = (unsigned char*)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
        }
        outf.close();
        return total;
    }

    string getBits(unsigned char X)
    {
        stringstream itoa;
        for(unsigned s = 7; s > 0 ; s--)
        {
            itoa << ((X >> s) & 1);
        }

        itoa << (X&1) ;
        return itoa.str();
    }

    void writeBits(ofstream& outf)
    {
        outf << *c;
    }

    ~bitChar()
    {
        if(c)
            free(c);
    }
};


int main()
{
    ofstream outf("ssSample.dat",ios::binary);

    string text ="00000110101011100010001011111110011011110101100101110101101111010111111110101011"
"00111011000011100011100000100010111110111110111001100001110001110000101001111010"
"00000101";
    cout<< text<<endl;

    //write to file
    bitChar bchar;
    bchar.setBITS(text);
    bchar.insertBits(outf);

    outf.close();

    ifstream inf("ssSample.dat" ,ios::binary);
    //READ FROM FILE
    string temp=bchar.readByBits(inf);

    cout << endl;
    cout << temp << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Narrow down your problem using a [testcase](http://sscce.org). You could have a reading problem, or an arithmetic problem, and I'm not going to figure out for you which one it is!

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit thanks. i edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `LF` Line Feed character.  This is the character that is getting omitted.

```
0000 1010
```

This may be unrelated, but Windows requires a `CR` and `LF` for a new line.  This code may act differently in Windows vs. Unix.

Read one byte at a time.

```
string readByBits(ifstream& inf)
{
    string s ="";
    char buffer[1];
    while (inf.read (buffer, 1))
    {
       // string strInput;
        //getline(inf, strInput );

        //for (int i =0 ; i < strInput.size() ; i++)
        //{
            s += getBits(*buffer);
        //}
    }
    return s;
}
```

Program output:

```
000001101010111000100010111111100110111101011001011101011011110101111111101010110011101100001110001110000010001011111011111011100110000111000111000010100111101000000101

000001101010111000100010111111100110111101011001011101011011110101111111101010110011101100001110001110000010001011111011111011100110000111000111000010100111101000000101
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your approach is that your text must be a multiple of 8 bits to work. Otherwise, even if everything is correct, that last character will be read from the file and converted to 8 binary digits in the string adding trailing zeros.

Comment: Ok I Know  `is not a multiple of 8-bits` and I handled it.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I quickly identified (but I assume there are more)

1. Your input **is not** a multiple of 8-bits
2. By using getLine you're reading until you meet a delimiting character and thus spoiling your result since you're not dealing with a text-based file

Comment: Ok I Know  `is not a multiple of 8-bits` and I handled it.i think number 2 is not a problem in my case.if i am false please explain biger

Comment: SethB answer is exactly my point 2: you were reading as a text what you wrote as binary and thus you were missing some data because text ignores line control characters. Understood?